# DDD reusable models

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a few microservices that reuse similar models i.e.

- RepairService
- InventoryService
- AuctionService

An Item (Cars, Bikes, etc) can be found in each of these services and each time I add new properties or a new item type, I then end up duplicating these models in 3 places

I thought about putting these models in a fourth library "ItemService" but since these models have different methods in each service, then InventoryService would be able to repair items, etc

But what if my "ItemService" only contained interfaces for these models (Just the state not the methods) which the other services then implement, so you could find ICar in the ItemService, package it into RepairService which then implements it and adds methods to repair a car.

I can't seem to find anywhere on the internet about having domain entities implement interfaces, so I'm not 100 percent sure

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In a previous project we ended up creating a separate library with all the common stuff used by different microservices. I think it is similar situation with what you describe here. The difference seems to be we used only plain beans for the models (not recommended when you do DDD, I know).

Taking this difference into account, what about using a Decorator?
This means you define the common properties/behavior in a common library, and them decorate them with the needed responsibilities in each service you use?

And I would not worry about having domain entities implement interfaces, if you think it is useful, just do it. I cannot think of any disadvantage.

Answer (score 0):

I have a bit of a [write-up](http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb/bounded-contexts) around the same concept.

The point is that the various bounded contexts do something different on the same *`thing`* so even though there would be a unique identifier for a specific instance of, say, `Car` you would have different implementations of that class in the various bounded contexts.  In many, if not most, cases you would probably have a class with a more relevant name in each particular BC.

Only a single one of the bounded contexts would, however, be the *system of record* for the entry.

Comment: I totally understand that there is BC, I don't want to share behaviour but I do want to share common data. i.e. I don't want to go into all 3 services to add a "Radio" property to a car. I want that brought in via a package of ICar (With only data no methods) which would have the Radio property on it, forcing each service with its own implementation of ICar to then have the common data but its own behavior. But I have no idea if that's bad practice

Comment: Typically an entity would not have an interface unless you are making some domain-specific role explicit; which is usually a technical mechanism in any event.  You are moving into the realm of canonical models which I am no fan of.  Are you absolutely sure that you want to bring `Radio` into all BCs though?  There may be concepts that are more related to each BC.  `Car` and `Bike` may be a `MachineType` and a `Gearbox` may be a `Rotable` or `Component` or some such in the `Maintenance` BC.  This is where you are going to have to be guide by what the UL.